# Variation of the BASE Current with the COLLECTOR Current in CE config?

Tags: transistors

So can anyone explain me how the *collector voltage*(V (output)) will vary with variation in *base current* with respect to the following figure?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRtGmf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to jump (maybe not in at the deep end but) in a bit deeper and I would recommend studying the following graphs for a BC547 transistor. The data sheet is [here](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/BC/BC547.pdf): -

[image]

The top-left graph shows quite a few things: -

- For a given base current, altering the collector-emitter voltage (above saturation) you can see that the transistor tends to behave like a constant current source.
- In saturation the transistor tends to behave like a variable resistor i.e. a given bas current means that the collector current is roughly proportional to collector-emitter voltage (nice for variable gain control)

The top-right graph indicates what voltage can be expected to be seen on the base for driving a certain collector current with collector-emitter voltage held at 5V.

Bottom-left indicates how much current gain you can expect from the device.

Bottom-right is another representaion of what happens in the saturation region.

> So can anyone explain me how the collector voltage(V (output)) will
>   vary with variation in base current with respect to the following
>   figure??

The trick here is asking the question how the collector current will vary with base current and once you have that you can decide what volt-drop will be across the resistor. From this you can check that the transistor is not entering saturation (because that puts you in the linear parts of the curves where collector current is more defined by collector voltage) and you'll need to re-appraise what the collector current is to recalculate the resistor volt-drop (iterations needed).

The bottom line is - try to fully understand the top-left graph - imagine a base current of (say) 200uA - ask yourself what collector current flows when the CE voltage is between 4V and 14V - the answer is about 50mA - hence the BJT is generally regarded as producing a constant current for a given base current but, the reality/detail is that collector current will vary between about 47mA (4V on collector) and 53mA (14 volt on collector). You might also start to notice that all the "constant-current" sections have an ever increasing slope and they all "point" to a position on the X-axis that is the same - it's called the Early voltage but a little too much to go into at the moment!!

Try to get a feel for this and recognize the onset of saturation and how it reshapes what I've just said - you can see, that for lower base drives, saturation is entered when collector voltage is less than 1V but, at higher base drives, saturation is entered at 2V or more - there is no exact definition of saturation that can be derived from the graphs so you just have to develop a gut-feeling for what it means.

Answer (score 0):

In figure, BJT is working in `Common-Emitter` configuration. Sine the input source is a current source(Actually it is a `current controlled current source`, but from the figure we can't trace any dependency of current source ), it will act as the `base current` here.

```
So, Ib = VCS
```

Since BJT is in CE-configuration, output current can be shown as

```
Collector current, Ic = hfe x Ib = hfe x VCS; where hfe is the gain
```

So from the equation, when VCS increases, Ic increases and there by voltage drop across `Resistor Rc` increases. This will reduce output voltage Vo.(since Vo = Vce)

```
Apply KVL rule, we have
    V = voltage across Rc + Vce = Vrc + Vo
Hence,
    Vo = V - Vrc
```

So as VCS increases, Vrc increases and hence output reduces.

Please correct me if I have error. No one is perfect.Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey!! How did you apply KVL to Transistor circuits??

Comment: @TheDreamCoder17:    we can apply kvl rule for transistor circuit also. if you look the circuit line that consist of `Rc` and collector emitter junction.. we can apply kvl and conclude that `Vrc +  Vce = Vcc`. This equation is always true. Do you have a different opinion?

Answer (score 0):

The Collector current **Ic** is related to your base current **Ib** using the relation **Ic=(hfe)(Ib)** where **hfe** is typical for your transistor. Hence, Collector voltage will be given by the eaquation **Vc=V-IcR=V-(hfe)IbR**. Hence the graph between collector **Ib** and **Vc** will be a straight line with a negative slope.